# Input to Unsigned Char Array

Tags: c, arrays, input, char, unsigned

I've been working on an encryption program at the bit level, I have everything working except one minor detail, I have to hard code my unsigned chars...  What I would like to do is prompt the user for two things:

-text, take the text and put them into my unsigned char array(including the spaces).

-numbers, take the numbers and put them into another unsigned char array(no spaces).

Example of text array:

input given:hello world

```
unsigned char text[11] = {'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d'}
```

Example of numbers given(note, I don't want the '123' in the array but 123):

input given: 123 213 146 178

```
unsigned char text[4] = {123, 213, 146, 178}
```

Update: I got the text going into the array and encoding it just fine. Thanks for the help. I'll tackle inserting the encoded numbers tomorrow.

Update 2: I stayed up... Code is working at decoding. Breaks on long sentences. will look into it tomorrow. thanks guys! :)

Comment: I'm just asking for a point in the right direction for what to use. scanf(), obviously isn't the right way. I'm just wondering how to parse the data. I'm new to C as I started coding in java, so I'm redo-ing old code to learn. I've done the more complicated bit comparison. I know how to prompt for data using scanf and store it individually into the array... I want to take it all in and separate it.

Comment: "scanf(), obviously isn't the right way" -- are you asking questions, or answering them? scanf is one way among several to read input ... there's no obvious reason you can't use it, or even an unobvious reason.

Comment: @VisioN So what if it were homework? Homework questions are welcome at SO.

Comment: @VisioN See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @JimBalter What do you mean by "welcome at SO"? The Meta discussion is about tagging question as homework and possible (informal) ways of treating the question if it is considered to be a way to solve someone's homework. My comment was stating that the question looks like a homework which means that I don't see any evidence of attempting to solve the problem by the OP. What's wrong with it? How can the question be welcome?

Comment: @VisioN I never asked for anyone to solve this for me, I asked for help on what to research. I learnt a lot about C without getting spoon fed. Relax, can you not see from the comments I got it done and no one gave me the direct answer. kinda sad i couldn't fgets(), but I could munipulate bits. now I see why you questioned it

Comment: @AiguoNgan7 Is your array big enough to hold all the characters you give as input? If not, you will end up trying to write in memory which has not be allocated which will result in segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the answer as `gets()` is deprecated.

A hint to one of the approaches you can take to solve your problem.

For the first part of you question, use `fgets()`.

For the second part, use `fgets()` to get the entire input, break them into tokens using space as delimiters ( `strtok()` will do ) and use `atoi()` to get its integer value and store it in the array.

Comment: Thanks, this is the type of comment I was looking for.

Comment: @AiguoNgan7:
gets() is not to be used. its deprecated.. instead use fgets()
please edit..

Comment: Never ever ever recommend `gets`.

Comment: Ok so I got the input going into my array using fgets(myArray,256,stdin). Is there a way to find the number of chars that were entered? I tried iterating over the array for NULL or '' with a counter. neither worked...

thanks, strlen -1 worked :D

Comment: @AiguoNgan7 *I tried iterating over the array for NULL or '' with a counter. neither worked...* -- your miscoding it doesn't mean it's not a way ... but you can just use strlen. It will include the newline. You also might consider using scanf, or fgets and sscanf, with the %n pseudo-format specifier.

Comment: @AiguoNgan7 "strlen -1 worked" -- A file need not end with a newline ... it's better to explicitly check if there is one.

Comment: This worked beautifully, I was able to see how to use them on tutorialspoint. 

Thank you for the help! I learnt a lot

Answer (score 0):

I followed Raunak Mukhia's logic, it worked!
"
Updating the answer as gets() is deprecated.

A hint to one of the approaches you can take to solve your problem.

For the first part of you question, use fgets().

For the second part, use fgets() to get the entire input, break them into tokens using space as delimiters ( strtok() will do ) and use atoi() to get its integer value and store it in the array.

"

Thank you!